# Angular 4 unit test, but getting error No provider for Http

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to learn how to run a unit test component on angular 4, but I'm not getting success, when I run the test with the code below I get this error:

> Error: No provider for http! and Failed:  :
>   could not find an object to spy upon for filexGeneralData()

I don't know if I'm on the right way...

Take a look at my code

**my spec file**

```js
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { filex } from '../../../models/filex';
import { filexService } from '../../../services/filex.service';
import { fileyfilexComponent } from './filey-filex.component';
import { dataService } from '../../../services/data.service';

describe('fileyfilexComponent', () => {
  let filexService;
  let myComponent;
  let fixture;
  let element;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [fileyfilexComponent],
        providers: [filexService, dataService],
        imports: [HttpModule]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(inject([filexService], s => {
      filexService = s;
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(fileyfilexComponent);
      myComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
      element = fixture.nativeElement;
    }));

  it(
    'should call getUsers and return list of users',
    async(() => {
      const response: filex[] = [];

      spyOn(filexService, 'filexGeneralData').and.returnValue(of(response));

      myComponent.method1();

      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(myComponent.datafilex).toEqual(response);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: It looks like all you may need to do is add `HubWrapperComponent` to the providers array in your spec. Of course, you would have to import it in the spec, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to include `HubWrapperComponent` in your `TestBed`. In the `providers` array, you need to include all of the services provided to your component being tested (better yet, you should provide "mocked" versions of those service). So, you could get the error to "go away" by simply adding `HubWrapperComponent` to the `providers` array in your `spec` file's `TestBed.configureTestingModule` method. It will end up looking like this:

*spec.ts*:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [IndicatorsDashboardComponent],
    providers: [DashboardService, DadosService, HubWrapperComponent],
    imports: [HttpModule]
  }).compileComponents();
```

---

An additional piece of advice: I would advise using jasmine to mock your `HubWrapperComponent` (which seems to be a wrapper over the `HttpClient`?).

```
mockWrapper = jasmine.createSpyObj('http', ['get']);
```

Then in your `providers` array:

```
{provide: HubWrapperComponent, useValue: mockWrapper}
```

That approach would look something like this:

```
  let mockHub: SpyObj<HubWrapperComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      mockHub = jasmine.createSpyObj('http', ['get']);

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [IndicatorsDashboardComponent],
        providers: [
          DashboardService, 
          DadosService,
          { provide: HubWrapperComponent, useValue: mockHub }
        ],
        imports: [HttpModule]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );
```

Mocking a service / anything that makes `Http` calls is preferred because you don't want to make real requests in your tests.

Comment: I changed `let mockHub: SpyObj<HubWrapperComponent>` to `let mockHub: Array<HubWrapperComponent> only for test because I got the error `Cannot find name 'SpyObj'.` and now I got `Error: No provider for Router!` and `Failed: Cannot read property 'buscarDadosDashboard' of undefined`...

Comment: So it looks like the Error for your question was solved. Now you can use a similar troubleshooting approach to solve this one, since it's essentially the same error, but for a different package. I'd recommend looking up something like "mocking Router for unit testing Angular"

Comment: Or you can use the exact same mocking method detailed in my answer and apply it to the Router. Either way, the error you were asking about is resolved and now you have a way to solve future errors of a similar nature.

Comment: Also it's not an array, it's a SpyObj and you have to import `SpyObj` from jasmine. (`import SpyObj = jasmine.SpyObj`)

Comment: When I try to import SpyObj from jasmine - `Namespace 'jasmine' has no exported member 'SpyObj'.`

Comment: Any idea how to import SpyObj?

Comment: You could type it as ‘any’ until you get it working. Not sure why the import isn’t working

Comment: Not yet, I got `No provider Router` and now `Failed: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` after apply the same method to router.

Comment: Oh okay, but the HubWrapperComponent is working now? There’s no error for it anymore? The Router thing is a separate mock and I would be happy to help you with it, but I’m not sure how I feel about providing the code in this answer since it is outside the scope of the original question. If you want to open a new question for the router issue I would be happy to help.

Comment: If you are still having an issue with importing the HubWrapperComponent I’d be happy to expand on my answer, but if the original error is no longer appearing, please consider upvoting and / or accepting the answer so other people know that your question has been resolved :)

Comment: now I'm getting error `Failed: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, I want to get SUCCESS for this test, but I don't know if I'm on the right way

Comment: Understood, please open a separate question because that error is unrelated to the one that you posted in this question. I am unable to answer the question because I don't know what other piece of code is causing the new issue and I only have 500 characters to respond! The error in this question has been resolved, as well as the Router mock apparently (using the same technique), so please consider accepting the answer so others know it has been solved and opening a *new* question with your current issue. Glad I could help :) Let me know when the new question is ready and I will take a look.

Comment: The new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811045/angular-4-unit-test-get-error-failed-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined