# Angular 4 unit test get error - Failed: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to get success on Angular 4 unit test, but I'm getting differents error, I'm getting the error `Failed: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

I'm using .map() only on service file but I don't know why showing this error

I'd like to know how can I get success for this test, and if, am I on the right way?

Take a look my code:

**My Spec**

```js
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { fileX } from '../../../models/fileX';
import { fileXService } from '../../../services/fileX.service';
import { fileYfileXComponent } from './fileY-fileX.component';
import { dataService } from '../../../services/data.service';
import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('fileYfileXComponent', () => {
  let fileXService;
  let myComponent;
  let fixture: any;
  let element;
  let mockHttp: httpClient;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
      mockHttp = jasmine.createSpyObj('http', ['get']);

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [fileYfileXComponent],
          providers: [
              fileXService,
              dataService,
              { provide: Http, useValue: mockHttp }
          ],
          imports: [HttpModule]
      }).compileComponents();
    }));

  beforeEach(inject([fileXService], s => {
      fileXService = s;
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(fileYfileXComponent);
      myComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
      element = fixture.nativeElement;
    }));

  it(
    'should get values',
    async(() => {
      const response: fileX[] = [];

      spyOn(fileXService, 'method1').and.returnValue(of(response));

      myComponent.searchdatafileX();

      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(myComponent.datafileX).toEqual(response);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Are you mocking the http service? Or actually sending requests to your server in a test?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are mocking the `HubWrapperComponent` correctly, such that it will not make a call to your back end every time you invoke `get`. In order to get this working, you'll need to use Jasmine's Spy utility, `returnValue` to tell the test what should be returned when `http.get` is called. Right now, this is not specified so the `map` is being called on `undefined`.

In your spec file, after the line:

```
mockHub = jasmine.createSpyObj('hubWrapperComponent', ['get']);
```

Add this line:

```
mockHub.get.and.returnValue(// your test response);
```

Based on the code in the service, my assumption is that you are expecting an Observable from the `get` method, so your `returnValue` call will look something like this:

```
mockHub.get.and.returnValue(Observable.of(
    { 
      json: () => { 
        return // object with properties you want to test 
      } 
    }
  )
);
```

More information on this method here: https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/Spy_and.html.

Comment: I got this error now `Failed: response.json is not a function`

Comment: You will need to add a `json` property to your test response. The `json` property should be a function which returns some JSON object with the data you want. I updated my answer with an example of how this would look. Your original error is solved though! :D

Comment: sorry but what exactly I have to put on `return // object with properties you want to test ` I tried to put somethings but got errors for all

Comment: I can’t tell you without seeing what you tried and what errors you got. The original error you asked about in this question has been solved. Some things to think about for the new error: what does it return in the real program (log it to the console and check)? What properties do you want to test? Since your original problem is solved, please consider accepting and / or upvoting this answer so others know it has been solved. If you are still stuck with the new error, please open a new question. Welcome to Stackoverflow and Good luck to you :)

Comment: actually my question is How to get success on this test =/ , but thank you for help me, I'll keep trying with your tips above.

Comment: I created a fakeData array with fake data and put on return, but I got this error `Expected undefined to equal [  ].`

Comment: I wish I could,  but I truly can't help you anymore at this point. The form your data must take is up to you. You can look at this guide: https://angular.io/guide/testing for more general information, but I've helped you as much as I can without being at your desk. And while your goal may be to get success on the test, the question is how to solve the error, which I answered and resolved for you. There is not enough code in your question that would allow me to "get your test working", and that wouldn't actually be a valid Stackoverflow question anyways. I believe you will get it working!